# Google Maps Api: any way to restrict a route within a country?

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm working on a Google Maps API for estimating delivery routes, and the default routes cross country borders back and forth if that would make the trip shorter.

Is there a way to restrict travel within the country?

For example going from Vancouver to Toronto without stepping foot in the United States?

I checked the documentation and didn't find anything relevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible do it on the request, But you can filter the list.
Using: **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json**
First on your payload use **{alternatives:true}** you will get different  alternatives.
After  get the list you will you need filter avoiding the country, html_instructions property have the string of the country.

```
`${step.html_instructions}`.includes("United States of America") === false
```

Using Lodash for the filter this is the example, preventing Unite State.

```
_.filter(directions.routes, (r: { legs: any[]; }) => r.legs.some((rx: { steps: any[]; }) => rx.steps.some((step: { html_instructions: any; }) => `${step.html_instructions}`.includes("United States of America"))) === false)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience is no way to limit directions to a particular country in the current API, but you could attempt to achieve it by setting waypoints. This will likely not result in an optimal route since you won't necessarily know the ideal location for the waypoint, and it would require iteratively getting driving directions until the entire route is within one country. You can see an example here:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_multi2.htm

Comment: Yes, it seems this feature is not currently available. Thanks.